# How to make nested RQL request

Tags: oracle, atg, atg-dynamo

I have a Dyn Admin repository with 2 descriptors: **sku** and **product**.

Could you please give an advice how to make nested RQL request, where I search for ids that returns from other RQL?

Something like this:

```
<query-items item-descriptor="sku" id-only="false">
id IN {
  <query-items item-descriptor="product" id-only="false">
    parentCategories CONTAINS "cat"
  </query-items>
  }
</query-items>
```

Comment: Can we assume that the skus that you are querying in an outer query, are child skus of the products of the inner query?

Comment: Dear @pantuptus, yes, exactly - childSKUs is equal to the product's id

Comment: Then wouldn't it work if you do it this way?
<query-items item-descriptor="sku" id-only="true">parentProducts includes item (parentCategories CONTAINS "cat") </query-items>

Comment: Many thanks, it is working. Could you please add this as answer and I will vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting is not supported but if skus that you are querying in an outer query, are child skus of the products of the inner query, then probably you can use the following:

```
<query-items item-descriptor="sku" id-only="true">parentProducts includes item (parentCategories CONTAINS "cat")</query-items>
```